# How can I write a function in objective-c, that I can use over any object in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, function

I want to create a function which I pass an object. Then, this function should print out some information for me.

like:

```
analyzeThis(anyObject);
```

I know about methods, but not how to make a function. As I understand, a function works global in all methods and classes, right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would do it the same way as any other function that you would write in C. So, if you have your function defined in a source file named `myLibraryFunctions.m`, anyone who wanted to use that function would include the header file where you define it (probably `myLibraryFunctions.h`, and then just make sure that they link with the object file (most of this will be done for you in Xcode if you simply create a file to house your "global" functions and include the header file for them in any source file that you access it from. Then just define it:

```
void analyzeThis(id anyObject);

void analyzeThis(id anyObject) {
    NSLog(@"Object %p: %zu, %@", anyObject, malloc_size(anyObject), anyObject);
}
```

But in reality, you would write whatever you wanted in your function. These functions don't have to be a part of any class definitions or anything like that. In this case, they're exactly the same as they would be in C.

Comment: Thanks! Where's the hidden option in XCode to set up that global function file, so that XCode would make all the header imports for me? That would be great!

Comment: Add the header import to your precompiled header. It will be the one with your project name and then _pch at the end. It is usually under the "Other Sources" group in an Xcode project.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to reimplement NSObject's description method? If you send an NSObject message it will return a string containing information about itself. You can override -(NSString*)description and add more information to this string.

If you do this, you'll find that magic happens - for example when you print an array object in the debugger it will iterate all the members of the array and print their descriptions.

Comment: Nice hint, thanks. Actually I wanted to try out something regarding memory management. A function that will check prior to an release message if the object still exists. May be useful. I'm not sure yet.

Comment: If you are creating that method for debugging, you really should look at using NSZombie.

If you are using it as a guard at runtime, it could cause other issues...

Comment: This seems completely distinct from NSZombie.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways exist for doing this:

- write a global function, just as you would do in C
- create a category of NSObject in which you implement a method which then will be available to all classes that have NSObject as ancestor.