# Cocoa - defining a global function like NSLog

Tags: ios, cocoa, function

See that post and the accepted answer :

[In XCode, is there a way to disable the timestamps that appear in the debugger console when calling NSLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354728/in-xcode-is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-timestamps-that-appear-in-the-debugger-co)

How may I, for that example or any other situation, declare a global function that include objective-c calls that I may be able to call directly, like NSLog, without having to make a call like [MyClass myFunction] ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I write an function in objective-c, that I can use over any object in my iPhone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788706/how-can-i-write-an-function-in-objective-c-that-i-can-use-over-any-object-in-my)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the standard C syntax; remember, Objective-C is a strict superset of C.

In a `.h` file, write the declaration

```
extern return_type function_name(argument_type1 argument_name1,argument_type2 argument_name 2);
```

and in a `.m` file (or `.c` file or whatever), write the implementation

```
return_type function_name(argument_type1 argument_name1,argument_type2 argument_name 2){
      ....
}
```

If it's in a `.m` file, it should be put outside of `@implementation ... @end` block. (Well, you can put your function within it, but I find it confusing.) That's it!

Comment: I have this error at compile time : Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_MyNSLog", referenced from:
      -[MyClass doJob:] in MyClass.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You forgot to include the `.m` file in your target, or your function implementation (in the `.m` file) has a name that’s different from the declaration in the `.h` file.

Comment: Thank you for this. I had been struggling to get the right implementation of something like this for a bit. Got it all going now.